# Prove that the function is differentiable

Tags: calculus

Let

$$  
f(x)= 
     \begin{cases}
       x^2\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{x^2}\right) &\quad\text{if} \hspace{5mm} x\in (0,1]\\
       0 &\quad\text{if} \hspace{5mm} \text{x = 0}
     \end{cases}   $$

Prove that the function is differentiable.

My try: I tried to use the limit to prove that the function is differentiable, but I didn't get anywhere, I think it's easier using "arguments", first of all I don't have any problems in $0$ beacuse the have the same value (it's continuous in $0$), and in the interval I want to say that decompostion is continuous because both are continuous, and the same argument for the product.

Do I need to use the fact that the function is differentiable at $a$ if $\lim_{h \rightarrow0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$?

Or do you think it is enough to say that?

Comment: Problem point is only $0$ and you need to show, that  limit from right exists in it.

Comment: It's simpler, in my opinion, to just use the definition, i.e., find the limit you mention towards the end of your question.

Comment: The old red herring.  Let $g$ be any bounded function defined on an interval containing $0$.  Then $x^2g(x)$ is differentiable at $x=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As we have
$$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0^+}\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h} =\lim_{h \rightarrow 0^+}h\cdot \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{h^2}\right)$$
then it's enough to find, that $\left| h\cdot \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{h^2}\right)\right| \leqslant |h|$.

Answer (score 1):

Differentiability requires more than continuity.  The limit definition of derivative that you quote at the end is the correct approach.

As @zkutch commented, at all points other than $0$, continuity is fairly straightforward, as the function is a composition of continuous functions such as polynomials, rational functions without zero denominators, and products and trig functions.

So write out the limit definition using $f(a) = 0$ and you should have it.

Comment: You're saying that I need to prove that the function is differentiable in $a=0$? or why do I need to do it for $f(a)=0$?

Comment: What I understand is apply the limit above to $a=0^+$ ... and I get the limit equal to 0, am I right?